# Exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: MultipartFile

Tags: spring-boot, react-redux

I'm using ReactJS frontend with SpringBoot and I get the above error. The root cause for this error is the MultiPartFile in DTO that I'm using to get data from the post request to the backend.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ItemDTO {
    private long craftId;

    private MultipartFile imgFile;

    private int itemQuantity;

    private String shortDescription;

    private String longDescription;
}
```

The nested exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

code from the Reactjs frontend with: import {Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input,FormText} from 'reactstrap';

```
<FormGroup>
     <Label for="exampleFile">File</Label>
     <Input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler} id="exampleFile" />
</FormGroup>
```

```
fileChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ image: event.target.files[0] })

}
```

the console.log of the payload:

```
image: File
name: "1605baeba66180d5337f41d9c80617a9.jpg"
lastModified: 1578835072895
lastModifiedDate: Sun Jan 12 2020 18:47:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
webkitRelativePath: ""
size: 45002
type: "image/jpeg"
__proto__: File
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first check try with the latest version.

Solution 1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Solution 2.

1. Set `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false` in application.properties

   **or**

   1. @Bean
      public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
      MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
          new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
      return converter;
      }